# Opening a .command file through AppleScript not working

Tags: macos, terminal, permissions, applescript

So I've recently been experimenting with using a self made AppleScript application to open a .command file. However, when I try to open the .command file using the AppleScript application, it says I don't have permission to access the file. I've already tried using chmod in Terminal to give myself access to the file, which allows me to open the .command file directly, but not through another application. Does anyone know how I can fix this issue?

Here is the error message I'm getting when I open the AppleScript application:
[image: Here is the error message I'm getting when I open the AppleScript application:]

And just in case, although I assume this is an issue with permissions, here is my AppleScript program:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    open "Users:G:Desktop:Programming:Python:start console.command"
end tell
```

Please let me know if any of this is unclear, it's been a while since I've posted

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The `start console.command` file needs to be made executable.

In Terminal, run the following command:

```
chmod u+x ~/Desktop/Programming/Python/start\ console.command
```

Comment: I did try that, but it only allows me to open it directly, rather than through the application